# How to Set Button Text to the Value of Two Added Integers?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

So I've been working on this android application which is basically an **Arithmetic** game. But I'm having a lot of trouble when it comes to processing answers in it.

I've seen apps that use buttons when making answers like I have indicated in the picture below.

[image: Graphic Illustration]

I keep wondering how people do this. Do I need to make a **totally** different activity for each question; or is there a way that all these calculations could be done?

In total my question is,

**How can I make an addition game where a random button adapts the answer of two integers and parses it as correct?**

If there is a library, or a game engine involved in doing this, then please indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be Somehing like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.__);
if(////){
button.setText(int 1 + int 2 + "" or " ");
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_background);
} else {
button.setText("you are wrong");
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_background);
}
```

Comment: This answer is honestly great! Thanks for the help!